# Marathon - do not redeploy app when return code = 0?

Tags: docker, mesos, mesosphere, marathon

We have a spring boot application deployed in a docker container and managed using mesosphere (marathon + mesos). The spring boot app is intended to be deployed via marathon, and once complete, it will exit with code = 0.

Currently, every time the boot application terminates, marathon redeploys the app again, which I wish to disable. Is there a setting that I can set in the application's marathon json config file that will prevent marathon from redeploying an app if it does not exit with a non-zero code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to run one-time jobs, I think [Chronos](https://github.com/mesos/chronos) would be the right tool. Marathon is, as Michael wrote, for long-running tasks.

Comment: Yes, I was looking into the same thing. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I think there's a principled problem in the understanding of what Marathon does: it is meant for long-running tasks (or put in other words: there's a `while` loop somewhere in there, maybe an implicit one). If your app exists, Marathon sees this and assumes it has failed and re-starts it again.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. Thank you.